# In FreeBSD, when executing pkg upgrade, what is the meaning of the reported number of "candidates"?

Tags: freebsd

On a FreeBSD system, when executing "pkg upgrade", there is a message indicating the number of candidates.  The pkg documentation does not clarify what these candidates are, or any way to list them.

Example output on a new system...

> pkg upgrade

```
Checking for upgrades (1 candidates): 100%
Processing candidates (1 candidates): 100%
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
Your packages are up to date.
```

Since the candidates remain after running the command, they cannot be an indication of upgradable packages.  So what is a "candidate"?   Is there any way to list the candidates?

Answer (score 1):

A 'candidate' is an equivalent of 'potentially affected package'. Life example shows:

```
# pkg upgrade -n
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
Checking for upgrades (251 candidates): 100%
Processing candidates (251 candidates): 100%
The following 250 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
ImageMagick-6.9.9.28_2,1

New packages to be INSTALLED:
xkeyboard-config: 2.24_1
...
Number of packages to be removed: 1
Number of packages to be installed: 9
Number of packages to be upgraded: 195
Number of packages to be reinstalled: 45
```

Comment: But in my example, there are no updates pending.  So what does "potentially affected" mean if there is no pending package update?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure. I guess the exact number of upgraded packages is known after the complete tree of the dependencies has been traversed. From my example can be seen that the estimation was "251 candidates"  and in the end only 250 packages were removed, installed, upgraded and reinstalled. I think this may be influenced by the fact that the ports tree is changing. Some ports may be removed or renamed.